# Repeat a time-series function over subjects and find an optimal interval

Tags: r

Lets say I study the reaction time of an animal.
At specified time points an animal is presented with a stimuli and the reaction time is registered.

```
# Registrations were done on the following occasions (minutes)
intervals <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

# Read in example data (this is how my data looks)
data <- read.table(header=T, text="
id value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 value6 value7
a 1.1 2.2 3.3 4.3 5.7 5.5 3.1
b 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5 4.5 3.5
c 3.4 6.4 8.9 9.1 10.3 8.0 5.4
")

# a simple plot showing the first animal's results
plot(intervals, data[1,2:8]); lines(intervals, data[1,2:8])

# For each animal I need to find the X value for a reaction time of 3.0 (for instance)
# I do this with 'optimize'. For the first animal (id='a'):
approx <- approxfun(intervals, data[1,2:8])
optimize(function(t0) abs(approx(t0) - 3), interval = c(2, 5))[[1]]
[1] 2.727291
```

But doing this for one subject at a time is very time consuming... Particularly the part where I have to provide the suitable interval (above: interval = c(0, 7)); the function can return wrong results if the interval is misspecified.

I've tried dplyr to do this both rowwise() and group_by() but without any success.

Any suggestions? Those are much welcome

Comment: Interested to see what you tried with dplyr. Do you use a specific interval for all animals, or each animal has it's own?

Comment: Thanks AntoniosK, for your reply below. Each animal actually has a specifik interval. Thats the tough part I believe.

Comment: With specific interval I mean an optimal interval to be specified in optimize(). As in Your previous suggestion, with the polynomials and linear model (other question I posted recently) you noted that the number of polynomials will vary according to each animal/person.

Comment: So now I'm using 2 to 5, but each animal will have a pre-specified one, right? It will be possible with dplyr if you specify the starting and the ending point of the interval for each animal and you use it as columns in your dataframe. The way to find those intervals might have to be another process before this.

Comment: I tried your solution below, it did work out in my data set. As we both suspected, the fixed interval leads to some erroneous results for some individuals. The process that finds these intervals puzzles me, as do many other things in R-world =)

Comment: Good that it worked. That means that if we manage to create a process that finds the interval for each animal (as I mentioned above) we will be able to use it using this method. Do you have any ideas to find the interval? How did you pick the one you used above?

Comment: Exactly, but I cannot figure that out, without looking at the graph manually. I plot the graph for each person and find (by looking at the graph) the approximate x value, and then specify the interval with a marginal around that approximation.

Comment: Well, that's the point! To program what you do manually. The way to do that is for a given animal to try various polynomials (1,2,3,...) and stop when the line is close (or on) the points. That could be done by calculating the errors/distance between points and your line. When that error is small enough for you you keep up to that polynomial.

Comment: But it surprises me that there is no R function to find X and Y coordinates as desired here. It's a struggle =)

Comment: Maybe an easier way to do it is to find the interval in which your point belongs, spot the area you need to focus and apply a model to predict your value. Eg. 3 belongs between 2.2 and 3.3, so your area is created by points (2, 2.2) and (3, 3.3). Apply a linear model which gives you a straight line connecting those points and predict the value at 3. No need to worry about the whole fitting, but to that specific area. Does it make sense? I can work on that when I find time.

Comment: It sounds very wise to do such a thing, however I'm not skilled enough. If you can find any time, I'll be enormously grateful. Thanks so far!

Comment: Now that I see you want to focus on specific y axis points to predict/find x axis points it seems better to focus on areas near those points rather than worrying about fitting the whole data. I'll have a look at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer that ignores the `optimise` approach and instead it picks the specific area (range) to optimise. This will be a line that conects two points via a linear model. Then it uses this model to predict.

I'd strongly recommend to run the process step by step to see how your initial dataset gets reshaped and updated.

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(tidyr)

# Registrations were done on the following occasions (minutes)
intervals <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

# Read in example data (this is how my data looks)
dt <- read.table(header=T, text="
                   id value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 value6 value7
                   a 1.1 2.2 3.3 4.3 5.7 5.5 3.1
                   b 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5 4.5 3.5
                   c 3.4 6.4 8.9 9.1 10.3 8.0 5.4
                   ")



# input measurement to investigate
y_input = 3

# create process
gather(dt,x,y,-id) %>%                                # reshape dataset 
  mutate(x = as.numeric(gsub("value","",x))) %>%      # get the minutes as a number from your column
  arrange(id,x) %>%                                   # need to order on id and x to visualise results  
  group_by(id) %>%                                    # for each animal
  mutate(lagx = lag(x, default=x[1]),                 # create columns with previous x and y values
         lagy = lag(y, default=y[1])) %>%                                       
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(flag = (between(y_input, y, lagy) | between(y_input,lagy,y))) %>%        # flag when measurements y belong to that range
  filter(flag == TRUE) %>%                                            # keep the rows with the appropriate ranges
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice(1) %>%                                  # keep only first range in case of multiple ranges for a specific animal
  do({x=c(.$x,.$lagx)                           # build a model (line to connect points) and predict
  y=c(.$y,.$lagy)
  model = lm(x~y)
  xpred = predict(model, newdata=data.frame(y=y_input))
  data.frame(xpred)})

#     id    xpred
#   1  a 2.727273
#   2  b 2.500000
```

Note the process recognises that animal with id = c has it's first measurement value equal to 3.4 and excludes it as 3 doesn't belong in a range (between two measurements). If you want to investigate measurement = 4 animal c will be included as well.

Try to experiment with the process using various numbers to test if it is correct for you. You might be able to spot any bugs.